# How do I reset the buffer which the flag is D3D11_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_COUNTER

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-11

I am trying to use a UAV buffer which the flag is `D3D11_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_COUNTER` in the pixel shader. For each pixel sent to the pipeline,the buffer will increase counter by using `IncrementCounter()`, which works well in the first frame.

However,in the second frame, the counter was added base on the first frame. It is obvious that it will overflow few frames later.
I had tried to use `ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint()` function(useless) or do something in the compute shader as follow:

```
[numthreads(1,1,1)]  
void ResetCS()  
{  
    while(FLBufferUAV.DecrementCounter());  
}
```

However for each frame the counter will be added up to more then 10^6, it is slow.
By the way, Anyone who has used effect11Frame? I have another question.

---

### `answer:`

I have already found the way to reset the counter.
the last parameter of `OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews()` is used to initialize the counter value.
I did't find this problem because I use the effect11Frame to simplify my code.
However the `OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews()` function is Hidden in the effect11Frame.I don't know whether should I rewrite it or just discard effect11Frame.

Comment: It seems to me that information would be useful. You should perhaps consider enhancing your above edit and answering it yourself instead of putting the answer in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is my first time to ask question.

Comment: If you use fx framework, you can call OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews with the D3D11_KEEP_RENDER_TARGETS_AND_DEPTH_STENCIL option, and reapply your uav with 0 in counter (You need to do it just after ApplyPass). Another option, since you have effects11 source code, is to add counter support in UAV variable type (have that around if you want).

Comment: Thank you. It's an efficient way! But if I use fx framework, some problems will happen when I use the PIXWin DEBUG mode. Maybe the version of my fx framework is too low.